# Automator: move files to a dynamically created folder name from subfolder

Tags: finder, automator, script

I'm trying to move downloaded files to a new folder(Get name from subfolder files).

Example:

```
Parent Folder
├── 160x600-SubFolder1.1
│   ├── AnotherSubFolderEN-Test display_a98765bcd0e12345fg
│   │    └── Filename-Test display_gf54321e0dcb98765a.png
│   │
│   └── AnotherSubFolderDE-Test display_a98765bcd0e12345fg
│        └── Filename-Test display_gf54321e0dcb98765a.png
│
└── 300x600-SubFolder-2.1
     ├── AnotherSubFolderEN-Test display_a98765bcd0e12345fg
     │   └── Filename-Test display_gf54321e0dcb98765a.png
     │
     └── AnotherSubFolderDE-Test display_a98765bcd0e12345fg
         └── Filename-Test display_gf54321e0dcb98765a.png
```

I want to automate it using Quick Actions and used the SubFolder(1.1/2.1) name before the dash as the file name(160x600_image.png) and move the file to a new Folder with the name from AnotherSubFolder before the dash(AnotherSubFolderEN).

Result will be:

```
Parent Folder
├── AnotherSubFolderEN
│   ├── 160x600_image.png
│   └── 300x600_image.png
│
└── AnotherSubFolderDE
    ├── 160x600_image.png
    └── 300x600_image.png
```

What I did was get the first name of the folder but I'm having a hard time getting the subFolder as I'm not familiar with shell scripting.

[image: awkprint]

Any ideas? I checked around here and can't find something including the sub folders in script.

Comment: The challenge with these kind of questions is to learn about all the rules which come into play. In the specific case I for instance wonder how a script can figure out the `AnotherSubFolderEN` part of the existing directory names. Also, on which directory do you want to set the Folder Action (on `Parent Folder`) and what is getting written there (always the whole sub-structure, or only the image files)?

Comment: What I'm thinking is getting the folder directory and removing the path before and after the dash,`${AnotherSubFolderEN%-*}`. This action will be set to Parent Folder and what is written is the whole sub-structure with the image file being move to the said new structure.

Comment: I assume we are not seeing the actual names of these directories currently, so it's hard to say whether this will work or not.